# Inject Spring config file into Ejb using Annotation

Tags: spring, ejb-3.1, ejb-2.x

Am trying to migrate project from ejb2.1 to ejb3.1. In my current project's ejb-jar.xml, i am using  for loading the spring configuration xml file{which initializes the beans which going to be called in ejbbean class in onEjbCreate() method using "getBeanFactory().getBean("somespringclass") }.

```
Sample environment entry: <env-entry>
                 <env-entry-name>ejb/BeanFactoryPath</env-entry-name>
                 <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                 <env-entry-value>config/xyz.xml</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>
```

what is the ideal syntax for using annotation(ejb3.1) in ejbbean class so that i can remove   in ejb-jar.xml.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you rejecting the edits ?

Comment: Sorry , am new to this forum but i did not reject edits.

Answer (score 0):

Just annotate your EJB-3.1 interface with `@EJB` and put the following in your Spring configuration XML:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="<your-ejb-package-e.g.-com.ejb.sample>" />
```